# Right to be photographed in public area

Tags: photography, consent

I know the general answer to being photographed in public is legal. But what if they photograph me without my permission. I am talking about my face. In public, do I not even have the right to my own face? It happened out in public when this random dude just started to point a camera towards me. I told him to delete the photo of me but he said in a public space, there is no sense of privacy. How do I prevent this from happening again? In case if you are wondering, there is creepy dudes who film strangers for fun.

Comment: Since you know the answer, what is the point of asking, other than to to complain about a legal fact that you don't like? Politics SE is where you complain about laws you don't like.

Comment: @user6726 Politics SE is not a dumping ground for personal opinions, thank you. Asking for rationale about why laws are as they are, for example, is on-topic. Complaining about them, most definitely is not.

Comment: You've got to come to terms with the realities of 21st century. Another 10-20 years and cameras will be chipped in human heads so that you won't even know they're taking pictures of you pretty close-up from a distance. If you can be seen, you can be remembered with however much detail people are capable of remembering. You can't stop people around you from using their eyes and brains full stop.

Answer (score 2):

your question is:

> How do I prevent this from happening again?

1. Don't go out in public.
2. Wear a disguise, dark glasses, a wig, make-up, etc.
3. Make yourself uninteresting to photograph.
4. or Don't let it bother you.